# JSON Output remains undefined within code but alert is fine, is this an issue with scope?

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, scope

I'm using the Facebook graph API to get a user's friend list and generate a status message based on a template and random friends. If I use `alert(response.data[0].name);` instead of `return(response);` my code works and I see the name of the first Facebook friend. When I take it further in my code, it throws an error as undefined. Based on a few hours of trying to work out the problem, I'm thinking I have some kind of issue with scope that doesn't allow me to use the response any longer or a problem with JSON formatting. I tried playing around with jQuery's JSON parse as well but didn't gain anything additional there.

```
shuffle = function(v){
    for(var j, x, i = v.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = v[--i], v[i] = v[j], v[j] = x);
    return v;
};

function getFriends() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.session && response.perms) {
        FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
            return response;
        });
        }
    } , {perms:'publish_stream'});
};

function selectFriend(){
    var friends = getFriends();
    friends = friends.data[0];
    var findex = friends.length
    var randomNumber = (Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 ) % findex);
    return(friends[randomNumber].name);
};

function process(status){
    status = status[0].toString();
    var cindex = status.indexOf("{{friend}}");

    while (cindex != -1){
        status = status.replace("{{friend}}",selectFriend());
        cindex = status.indexOf("{{friend}}");
    }
    return(status);
};

function newStatus(){
    var status = [
        "This status is named {{friend}}",
        "This status loves {{friend}} but likes {{friend}} too.",
        "This status goes by {{friend}} but you can call it {{friend}} if you like.",
        "This status hates {{friend}}"
    ];

    status = shuffle(status);
    $('#status').text(process(status));
}
```

The code begins with calling newStatus() on click.

**EDIT: Here's how I refactored my code to work after jfriend00's answer:**

```
shuffle = function(v){
    for(var j, x, i = v.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = v[--i], v[i] = v[j], v[j] = x);
    return v;
};

function newStatus(){
    var status = [
        "This status is named {{friend}}",
        "This status loves {{friend}} but likes {{friend}} too.",
        "This status goes by {{friend}} but you can call it {{friend}} if you like.",
        "This status hates {{friend}}"
    ];
    status = shuffle(status);
    status = status[0].toString();

    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.session && response.perms) {
        FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
            var friends = response.data;
            var findex = friends.length

            var cindex = status.indexOf("{{friend}}");

            while (cindex != -1){
                var randomNumber = (Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 ) % findex);
                var name = friends[randomNumber].name;

                status = status.replace("{{friend}}",name);
                cindex = status.indexOf("{{friend}}");
            }
            $('#status').text(status);
        });
        }
    } , {perms:'publish_stream'});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably that the calls to the FB api are asychronous.  That means when you call FB.api(), it starts an ajax call to FB.  Your other code continues to run while that ajax call is being completed.  In fact, your call to getFriends finishes and the rest of selectFriend() runs too before the FB ajax call has completed.

Then, when the FB api call does complete, it calls the completion function (probably where you put an alert).  In your code, you aren't doing anything meaningful in the completion function.  You're just returning the response with

```
return response;
```

But, that isn't doing anything useful.  That return value is not a return from the getFriends() function.  It's a return back to something inside the ajax engine.

If you want to do something useful with the `FB.api(`) response, you need to run that code or call that code from the completion function specified in the `FB.api()` call.

You would have to do something like this pseudo code:

```
function getFriends() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.session && response.perms) {
        FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
            var friends = response.data[0];
            var findex = friends.length
            var randomNumber = (Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 ) % findex);
            var name = friends[randomNumber].name;
            // now continue on with whatever you want to do with the random friend info
            // you cannot just return data from this callback, you have to actually carry
            // out whatever you were going to do with the data here
        });
        }
    } , {perms:'publish_stream'});
};

function selectFriend(){
    getFriends();
    // the getFriends() function is asynchronous and the FB.api() call has not yet
    // completed so we can't do anything here yet as we have to wait for the
    // FB.api() call to finish first.
};
```

Comment: First, thanks for your time, I appreciate it. I see what you're saying in regards to the timing and why it's failing outside of the call due to the next function being called before the data is ready. With your recommendation of essentially moving the logic to within the API call, I'd assume the intended result would be reached but I'd still be left with the issue of returning it from the API call. I can come up with a random friend's name (the purpose of the call), but it'll still be done too fast to use within the replace loop.

Comment: Logically, what you have to do is make the FB call and then do none of your other work yet.  When the FB call finishes and you now have the FB data, you call a function from the completion of the FB call that does all your other work because now you have the FB data.  You can't make an API call in the middle of a loop and expect to be able to use the result in the loop.  This is asynchronous programming.  It's a pain sometimes, but it's how ajax calls in the browser work.

Comment: Great, I've marked this answer complete as I've got things working now by refactoring all my functions to just execute before or within the async depending on what was needed. I'm posting my code above in an edit as well so anyone who's got a similar issue can hopefully benefit from your help as well.